# Redirecting traffic during restart or downtime in jboss EAP 5

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-6

I am using JBoss EAP 5.1 application server where I am trying a display a default HTML (error page) while the application is down or is restarting. What is the configuration required at server level to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure custom error pages for all applications on EAP 4/5 in the global web.xml which is located in `$JBOSS_HOME/server/$PROFILE/deployer/jbossweb.deployer/web.xml`